# Html.DropDownList passing as null using .val() in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to get the value of an item in a dropdownlist and pass it to the controller using an ajax post, but whatever I pass keeps returning as null.

**DropDownList:**

```
<div class="form-inline">
    @Html.DropDownList("People", null, new { @id = "personID", @class = "form-control" })
    <button onClick="setTimeout( initCalendar, 5000 );" type="button" id="btnInit" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-toggle="modal" href="#loadingModal" class="btn btn-info">Initialise Calendar</button>
</div>
```

**ajax post:**

```
function initCalendar() {
    // This function will be executed when you click the element
    // show the element you want to show
    $("#loadingModal").show();

    alert($('#personID').val(""));

    //var dataRow = {
    //    'ID': $('#personID').val()
    //};

    var dataRow = $('#personID').val();

    console.log(dataRow);
    console.log($('#personID').length);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: "/Event/SelectPerson",
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(dataRow)
    });

    startCalendar();

    // Set a timeout to hide the element again
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#loadingModal').modal('hide');
    }, 5000);
}
```

**Controller:**

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.Hours = GetHoursList();
        ViewBag.People = GetPeopleList();

        return View();
    }

    // Finds all people in the database and adds them to a list for a dropdownlist.
    public List<SelectListItem> GetPeopleList()
    {
        List<SelectListItem> peopleList = new List<SelectListItem>();

        var people = from s in db.People
                     select s;

        foreach (Person person in people)
        {
            peopleList.Add(new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = person.Forename + " " + person.Surname,
                Value = person.ID.ToString()
            });
        }

        //var sortedPeopleList = (from person in peopleList
        //                        orderby person.Text
        //                        select person).ToList();

        return peopleList;
    }

    public void SelectPerson(int ID)
    {
        Person person = db.People.Where(p => p.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();

        Session["Person"] = person;
    }
```

When I log the JSON, the ID is always null and I cant figure out why.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `console.log($('#personID').length);` return?

Comment: It returns 1 exactly.

Comment: That rules out duplicates. You will need to show some more code. What you have shown will not return `null` unless your options have `value=""` (which would not be the case based on your controller code) so there must be something else causing the issue.

Comment: Strange - I don't really know what else I can show, I've already added all the relevant code. I have updated the ajax post to include the whole 'initCalendar' function if that helps.

Comment: `alert($('#personID').val(""));` :) You should have known from your now deleted last question - `.val("")` sets the value to `null`

Comment: Sorry to be incredibly stupid again haha - I have a habit of not spotting the obvious. I was using that to debug my last question and forgot it was there... facepalm. Thanks again - much appreciated.

Comment: Do you want an answer added or will you delete this?

Comment: I deleted the last one as I felt the title was irrelevant to the solution and didn't want people stumbling across it and looking for an answer, but not finding one. If you want to add an answer, feel free and I will select it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following line

```
alert($('#personID').val(""));
```

is setting the value of the element with `id="personID"` to null. You need to change it to

```
alert($('#personID').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
var dataRow = $('#personID').val();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still gets parsed as null.